# javascript loading textures for webgl

Tags: javascript, arrays, opengl-es, webgl

Im trying to objectify an approach to loading textures in webgl. I have an array of planets set up to which I set an name and other values. All my textures are called sun.jpg, mercury.jpg etc so when I contstruct the name string I can use `Planets[i].name+".jpg"` to get the name of the texture. 
The error I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of
>   undefinedSpheredPlanetsGL.js:138
>   handleLoadedTextureSpheredPlanetsGL.js:179 TextureName.(anonymous
>   function).image.onload

I set up the textureName array like this: (this array holds the individual variables that i reference later)

```
var TextureName = [];
    function setBufferName()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < Planets.length; i++)
        {
            TextureName[i] = {name: Planets[i].name+"TextureName"};
        }
    }
```

Then I init the textures like this: (This should ensure that the "sunTextureName" should reference "sun.jpg" and so on for all the planets)

```
function initTexture() 
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < Planets.length; i++)
        {
            TextureName[i] = gl.createTexture();
            TextureName[i].image = new Image();
            TextureName[i].image.onload = function () 
            {
                handleLoadedTexture(TextureName[i]);
            }
            TextureName[i].image.src = Planets[i].name+".jpg";
        }
    }
```

The error then occurs here when "handleLoadedTexture(TextureName[i])" is called and im not sure why the function is this:

```
function handleLoadedTexture(texture) 
    {
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
        gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
    }
```

To be clearer the error occurs on this line  `gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);`. I dont know why because i pass in the variable and i should reference what is in the array.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope of your counter variable.
Your loop increments the counter variable and exits when its larger or equal to `Planets.length`. When your callback is executed the loop already finished and `i` is left at `Planets.length`.

You can use an IIFE(*immediately invoked function expression*) to create a scoped copy of `i` like so:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < Planets.length; i++)
    {
        TextureName[i] = gl.createTexture();
        TextureName[i].image = new Image();
        TextureName[i].image.onload = (function (index) {
            return function () { handleLoadedTexture(TextureName[index]) }
        })(i);
        TextureName[i].image.src = Planets[i].name+".jpg";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much it fixed everything!